# dynamic menu items using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

Let's say I have the following menu structure:

```
    <li class="dropdown"><img role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" ng-src="{{avatarUrl}}" />
      <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu">
        <li ng-hide="user"><a ng-click="openLoginDialog()">Login</a></li>
        <li ng-show="user"><a ng-click="logout()">Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
```

I get the correct menu, but because I'm using ng-show/ng-hide, when I change `user = false;` programmatically in the controller, the login menu appears. I get why this is happening, but I'm not sure what approach to take when using Angular to prevent it. I tried an ng-repeat:

```
    <li class="dropdown"><img role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" ng-src="{{avatarUrl}}" />
      <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu">
        <li ng-repeat="action in actions"><a ng-click="{{action.command}}">{{action.name}}</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
```

with:

```
$scope.actions = [ {
  name : "Login",
  command : "openLoginDialog()"
}, {
  name : "Logout",
  command : "logout()"
} ];
```

But with that strategy, nothing happens with I click the menu item. I'm not sure what the appropriate Angular approach is to what I'm sure is a pedestrian use case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [ng-switch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSwitch) instead of ng-show/hide.  ng-switch adds/removes elements from the DOM.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu">
    <li ng-switch="user">
       <a ng-switch-when="true" ng-click="logout()">Logout</a>
       <a ng-switch-default     ng-click="openLoginDialog()">Login</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Update** to handle @andyczerwonka's comment.  Move the ng-switch up one or two levels.  If `span`s inside `ul` don't bother you:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu" ng-switch="user">
  <span ng-switch-when="true">
    <li><a  ng-click="logout()">Logout</a></li>
    <li><a  ng-click="preferences()">Preferences</a></li>
  </span>
  <span ng-switch-default>
    <li><a ng-click="openLoginDialog()">Login</a></li>
  </span>
</ul>
```

Otherwise, how about one `span` outside the `ul`:

```
<span ng-switch="user">
  <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu" ng-switch-when="true">
      <li><a  ng-click="logout()">Logout</a></li>
      <li><a  ng-click="preferences()">Preferences</a></li>
    </ul>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu" ng-switch-default>
      <li><a ng-click="openLoginDialog()">Login</a></li>
  </ul>
</span>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/ELurv/) showing both methods.

Comment: This doesn't work for me because `ng-switch` won't work if I have more than two menu items. Let's say I want to show one menu item when the user is not logged in, e.g. login, and two when he is, e.g. Preferences and Logout. I don't think `ng-switch` will handle this case.

Comment: Using this method it behaves the same way as the `ng-show\ng-hide` strategy. On logout, the login menu appears.

Comment: Try putting up a fiddle or plunkr.

Comment: Here's [an example](http://plnkr.co/edit/3Bd7hajSlLwvUMPbmeMs?p=preview) of me trying to use `ng-repeat`, but the actions don't execute. [Here's a video](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/52968670/login_menu.swf) of the menu appearing on logout using the strategy you mention above. I'll try and extract it into an example.

Comment: I think it's more of a Bootstrap issue. http://plnkr.co/edit/wkUClK9OBLK8EWI5D8Fn?p=preview

Comment: Try this http://plnkr.co/edit/fmwJVl5wTcasUnjv9Oiz?p=preview
You need to do **$scope**.loggedIn = true/false;  In the controller methods, I added some jQuery to click the menu button to automatically close it.

Comment: I was actually able to get it to work by simply moving the `ng-switch` to a higher level. For some reason, the login menu does not appear anymore. I'm not fond of the solution, but it works. https://github.com/andyczerwonka/dolphin/blob/13de587a39f21e771eae591c5431a97ba0434970/public/app/partials/navbar.html#L11-L27

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22722/discussion-between-andyczerwonka-and-mark-rajcok)

Answer (score 1):

In my project I use the following setup:

```
angular.module('mymodule')
.controller('MenuCtrl', function ($scope, $translate, UserService) {
```

Define actions with roles that are allowed to use these actions:

```
  $scope.actions = [ {
    name : "menu.login",
    href : "#/login",
    roles : []
  }, {
    name : "menu.logout",
    href : "#/logout",
    roles : [ 'READ_ONLY', 'ADMIN' ]
  }, {
    name : "menu.foo",
    href : "#/foo",
    roles : [ 'READ_ONLY', 'ADMIN' ]
  }, {
    name : "menu.adminArea",
    href : "#/adminArea",
    roles : [ 'ADMIN' ]
  } ];
```

Define an isAllowed function that determines if an action can be used by the current user:

```
  $scope.isAllowed = function(action) {
    if (action.roles && action.roles.length) {
      for ( var i = 0; i < action.roles.length; ++i) {
        if (jQuery.inArray(action.roles[i], UserService.roles) >= 0) {
          return true;
        }
      }
      return false;
    } else {
      return !(UserService.roles && UserService.roles.length);
    }
  };
```

Then use $roueChangeSuccess event to determine which actions should be displayed for the current user:

```
  $scope.initView = function() {
    for(var i=0; i<$scope.actions.length; ++i) {
      var action = $scope.actions[i];
      if($scope.isAllowed(action)) {
        action.isRendered = true;
      } else {
        action.isRendered = false;
      }
    }
  };

  $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
    $scope.initView();
  });

});
```

Finally, this is my menu template:

```
<nav ng-controller="MenuCtrl">
  <ul>
    <span ng-repeat="action in actions" ng-switch on="action.isRendered">
      <li ng-switch-when="true"><a href="{{action.href}}">{{action.name | translate}
      </a></li>
    </span>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you assign functions to your commands:

```
var openLoginDialog = function() { ... };
var logout = function() { ... };

$scope.actions = [ {
  name : "Login",
  command : openLoginDialog
}, {
  name : "Logout",
  command : logout
} ];
```

Comment: I did, but the items won't execute when I add them this way. They show up just fine, but they won't execute. I'm not sure why.

Comment: I think its a problem with the angularjs version you have used . Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/m6H5K0v68Ku80WdP69DH?p=preview), where I used angular version 1.1.5 and its working fine . :)