# How can create a dynamic menu depending on the user's rights, in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

There is two similar questions:

- [dynamic menu items using AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14297116/196526)
- [How can I show or hide some buttons depend on the user's rights, in angularjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11150106/196526)

I need to create a dynamic menu exactly like in the first similar question exept I cannot hardcode the rights in my page. **An adminitrator can create custom roles and chose wich menu item this role can see**.

```
<li class="dropdown"><img role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" ng-src="{{avatarUrl}}" />
  <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu">
    <li ng-show="???"><a ng-click="action01()">Action one</a></li>
    <li ng-show="???"><a ng-click="action02()">Action two</a></li>
    <li ng-show="???"><a ng-click="action03()">Action tree</a></li>
    <li ng-show="???"><a ng-click="action04()">Action four</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

How should I imagine my strategy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create something like a HeaderController an attach to it a function that tells if a given role can do the given action. Presumably you have the ACL stored somewhere so perhaps you can create a service for it. Something like this:

```
controller('HeaderController', ['$scope', 'Acl', function($scope, Acl) {

    $scope.roleCanDo = function(role, action) {
        return Acl.roleCanDo(role, action);
    }

}])
```

and your view would be like this:

```
<li class="dropdown"><img role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" ng-src="{{avatarUrl}}" />
  <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu">
    <li ng-show="roleCanDo(currentUser.role, 'action01')"><a ng-click="action01()">Action one</a></li>
    <li ng-show="roleCanDo(currentUser.role, 'action02')"><a ng-click="action02()">Action two</a></li>
    <li ng-show="roleCanDo(currentUser.role, 'action03')"><a ng-click="action03()">Action tree</a></li>
    <li ng-show="roleCanDo(currentUser.role, 'action04')"><a ng-click="action04()">Action four</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Obviously the actual code will depend on your current system but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple to implement [Creating dynamic menu from database data using AngularJS](http://www.dotnetawesome.com/2015/12/creating-dynamic-menu-from-database-using-angularjs.html)

Suppose we have a table in our database for navigation menus like,

[Table structure for dynamic menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMCRz.png)

Write below code for fetch menus from database

```
public JsonResult GetSiteMenu()
{
    using (MyDatabaseEntities dc = new MyDatabaseEntities())
    {
        var menu = dc.SiteMenus.ToList();
        return new JsonResult { Data = menu, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
}
```

and here is the angularjs controller

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);
app.controller('menuController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.SiteMenu = [];
    $http.get('/home/GetSiteMenu').then(function (data) {
        $scope.SiteMenu = data.data;
    }, function (error) {
        alert('Error');
    })
}])
```

**HTML Code**

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="menuController">
        @* Here first of all we will create a ng-template *@
        <script type="text/ng-template" id="treeMenu">
            <a href="{{menu.Url}}">{{menu.Name}}</a>
            @* We will create submenu only when available *@
            <ul ng-if="(SiteMenu | filter:{ParentID : menu.ID}).length > 0">
                <li ng-repeat="menu in SiteMenu | filter:{ParentID : menu.ID}" ng-include="'treeMenu'"></li>
            </ul>
        </script>
        <ul class="main-navigation">
            @* Here we will load only top level menu *@
            <li ng-repeat="menu in SiteMenu | filter:{ParentID : 0}" ng-include="'treeMenu'"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```